# Print string to footer using wp_footer option

Tags: variables, footer

```
add_action('wp_footer','slider_option');

 function slider_option() { 
   $option ="<script>script function data
                    </script>"; 
    echo $option; 
 }
```

I want to print or you can say insert data in `$option` variable to footer menu

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you trying to load a script?

Comment: i want to print inline script to footer which is stored in variable thts it

Comment: try the wp_footer hook. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: you can also give me solution to inserting inline script to footer will be ok for me

Comment: i tried wp_footer hook not working :/ i echo string and also tried return string but both not working

Comment: you can just enqueue script and set the last paramater ($in_footer) to true. is this what you are looking for? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: are you sure in your template you are calling wp_footer();?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, technically. Something is happening in code not posted that is causing  your problem. I don't know how to guess at what. Where is this code? Is anything else hooked to that hook? Do you have this problem if you disable plugins or switch to a bundled theme?

Comment: see i m creating plugin for adding slider and  i want to add inline script to footer so tht slider will be in work
but the inline script from plugin not getting added to footer part of page i m using shortcode to add html markup of slider and using add_action('wp_footer','function name') to add script on footer of page but its not working i can add external scripts using enque scrpits and they are working properly i checked source code of page but at footer nothing is added

Comment: do you have wp_footer() just somewhere before the closing of </body> tag in your template?

Comment: <pre><script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/avm%20localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.50.0-2014.02.05'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
i got this when i include wp_footer()
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/avm%20localhost\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/avm%20localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.8.1'></script></pre>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have to use a variable for you script?

I have done this in the past and has worked...

```
// add script to the footer and break out of PHP
function slider_option(){ ?>

<script>script function data</script>

<?php } ?>

add_action('wp_footer','slider_option');
```

If this does not work make sure you have the footer hook in you themes footer template file.

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/avm%20localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.50.0-2014.02.05'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"http:\/\/localhost\/avm%20localhost\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/avm%20localhost/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=3.8.1'></script>
i got this when i added wp_footer(); at footer.php

Answer (score 0):

```
adding wp_footer() hook inside theme and then this code to add script to footer and worked fine for me 

function slider_option()
    {
    $default=array(     
        'effect'=> 'random',               // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        'slices'=> 15,                     // For slice animations
        'boxCols'=> 8,                     // For box animations
        'boxRows'=> 4,                     // For box animations
        'animSpeed'=> 500,                 // Slide transition speed
        'pauseTime'=> 3000,                // How long each slide will show
        'startSlide'=> 0,                  // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        'directionNav'=> true,             // Next & Prev navigation
        'controlNav'=> true,               // 1,2,3... navigation
        'controlNavThumbs'=> false,        // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        'pauseOnHover'=> false,             // Stop animation while hovering
        'manualAdvance'=> false,           // Force manual transitions
        'prevText'=> 'Prev',               // Prev directionNav text
        'nextText'=> 'Next',               // Next directionNav text
        'randomStart'=> false);
        extract($default);
        $slider_script;
         ?>  
        <script type='text/javascript'>
                $(window).load(function() {
          $('#slider_slide').nivoSlider({
            effect:<?php echo "$effect"; ?>,
            slices:<?php echo "$slices"; ?>,                     // For slice animations
            boxCols:<?php echo "$boxCols"; ?>,                     // For box animations
            boxRows:<?php echo "$boxRows" ?>,                     // For box animations
            animSpeed:<?php echo "$animSpeed"; ?>,                 // Slide transition speed
            pauseTime:<?php echo "$pauseTime"; ?>,                // How long each slide will show
            startSlide:<?php echo "$startSlide"; ?>,                  // Set starting Slide (0 index)
            directionNav:<?php echo "$directionNav"; ?>,             // Next & Prev navigation
            controlNav:<?php echo "$controlNav"; ?>,               // 1,2,3... navigation
            controlNavThumbs:<?php echo "$controlNavThumbs"; ?>,        // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
            pauseOnHover:<?php echo "$pauseOnHover"; ?>,             // Stop animation while hovering
            manualAdvance:<?php echo "$manualAdvance"; ?>,           // Force manual transitions
            prevText:<?php echo "$prevText"; ?>,               // Prev directionNav text
            nextText:<?php echo "$nextText"; ?>,               // Next directionNav text
            randomStart:<?php echo "$randomStart"; ?>

        });});  
        </script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_footer','slider_option');
     ?>

thank you for @mattroyal @reny and others  for your help
```

Comment: Awesome mate, glad you came right :-)